# Angularjs and ui-router, refresh all parent state on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m developping an angularjs application using ui-router and I m having some trouble.

Actually, I want to manage the state in te front end as musch a possible.

My problem is that, when connected, I store some informations concerning a user inside of a localstorage system.

When the browser refreshs (aka F5 press button), only the current state is refreshed.

It means that my parent jobs isn't done and that I don't have enough information on my current one to work, resulting in a standard :

```
Error: this.itemis null
```

How can I refresh all the parent state so that I'll have the good object passed from states to child states ?

Comment: in which state do you store to localstorage?
refreshing shouldn't effect localstorage... do you store everything you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data that you need to persist in a cookie, then on page reload load this data from the cookie.

See the angular docs for more information on how to put and get from cookies in angular. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies